# Help request understanding the use of SeedRandom

Tags: random

I want to use [SeedRandom](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeedRandom.html) inside of a code in which I use [SmoothKernelDistribution](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothKernelDistribution.html) to obtain the pdf of a stochastic process at a determined time as `empiricPDF1 = SmoothKernelDistribution[RandomVariable1Histogram]` Then, I want to do a Monte Carlo of the resulting random variable as `d1 = RandomVariate[empiricPDF1, 100000];`. Unfortunately, this code takes a lot of time to run and I get different results each time that I execute it.

I need someone to help me to understand how to use SeedRandom so that I don't have to generate a sample of 100k random numbers inside of d1 and instead always get the same 100k random numbers so that d1 always has the same values and hopefuly I also get a smaller running time.

Comment: You simply need to write e.g. "SeedRandom[1]". E.g.: `SeedRandom[1];
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {2}]`

Comment: @DanielHuber. Thanks for the answer. However, I am having another issue. I have written `SeedRandom[1]; RandomVariate[empiricPDF1, {100}]`, obtaining what I want. Hoever, I cannot seem to use it anywhere. `d1 = SeedRandom[1];` retuns the error `Part::partd: Part specification d1[[1]] is longer than depth of object.` and `imis = Table[
   isexpan /. {z1 -> SeedRandom[1][[k]], z2 -> SeedRandom[1][[k]]}, {k, 1, 
    nsim}];` also returns the same error. Can you please offer me further help?

Comment: "SeedRandom[1];"  resets the random generator.  Afterwards you get always the same series of random numbers. That is all you want. In addition it also returns data about the random number generator, but that is nothing you should play with. Therefore  do not write "d1 = SeedRandom[1];"

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks for the help, but could you please tell me then how to access to the data generated by `SeedRandom[1]; RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {2}]`

Comment: Say you want 100 real numbers. Then you write:  `SeedRandom[1]; data=RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {100}]`

Comment: @DanielHuber I have tested your solution as `SeedRandom[1]; d1 = RandomVariate[empiricPDF1, {100000}];` and it does work. If I run the code I get the desired results. However, I don't get how can I store the results. If I run the code again, it takes a lot of time to return the results. Also, if I comment the `d1 = RandomVariate[empiricPDF1, {100000}];` and only leave the `SeedRandom[1]` part, I get an error. So, what's the use of `SeedRandom`? just running the same program into the same session?

Comment: , I don't get how can I store the results": the result is stored in d1. Further, a second run should take the same time. "SeedRandom[1]" should not get an error, it resets the random number generator.

Comment: (1) You're having trouble with your code, but nobody can guess what code you are executing. The code you show in your comments (except for the `Table[..]` in the first one) do not give errors when run in a fresh kernel. To get useful help, post self-contained code that reproduces the error(s). (2) It's not entirely clear what you want. If you want the table of random values to persist from one kernel session to the next, look up `LocalSymbol` and consider using `LocalSymbol["d1"]` instead of `d1`. You might be interested in `DumpSave` and `Save`.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2425219).